# What do you call an animal being 'personified' as another animal?

Tags: personification

I was reading a poem earlier entitled 'A walk on the Beach' by Margaret Scott (I do not believe I fully understand the poem but that is not meant for here so), but one phrase was **'the crabs writhe**. I immediately associated this with a snake, but I wondered what this was called as that is personification but not?

Comment: Just because snakes writhe doesn't mean any time other things are described as writhing that it is a figure of speech meant to conjure up the image of snake.

Answer (score 2):

This could be called **zoomorphism**.

Usually, zoomorphism means ascribing characteristics of an animal to a non-animal, like a deity, human, or inanimate object, but it can also be used to attribute one animal's characteristics to another animal.

The term is similar to the more common literary term ***anthropomorphism***, where human characteristics are ascribed to a non-human.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoomorphism) provides a list of functions of zoomorphism that includes the meaning you describe here:

> - Art that imagines humans as non-human animals
> - ***Art that portrays one species of animal like another species of animal***
> - Art that creates patterns using animal imagery, or animal style
> - Deities depicted in animal form, such as exist in ancient Egyptian religion
> - Therianthropy: the ability to shapeshift into animal form
> - Attributing animal form or other animal characteristics to anything other than an animal; similar to but broader than anthropomorphism
> - The tendency of viewing human behaviour in terms of the behaviour of animals, contrary to anthropomorphism, which views animal or non-animal behaviour in human terms